# How the transaction isolation levels in ssis works?

Tags: ssis

I have few questions about ssis transction isolation levels.
         consider a scenario:I have an Execute SQL task which insert a data in a table A.This task is pointing to a dataflow task,which read the data which is previously inserted on A.I have started Distributed transaction and if i set transaction isolation in ssis as readcommited,whether it commit the table A at first execute sql task and move to dataflow task?
Also what about other isolation level in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand from your question you're asking what's the appropriate transaction isolation if you want to read data from a table in the same transaction that data is being written to the table? As far as I know, it shouldn't matter. The isolation types only address situations where another transaction wants to modify the same rows that the uncommitted transaction is modifying. In other words just reading the table should have no problems and you should see the data from the first Execute SQL task. Data written in a transaction is available before the transaction is committed.

For further reading, this is from the Oracle docs, but the same definition should apply to SQL and SSIS packages. Notice they address when two transactions want to modify the same data:

SERIALIZABLE: If a serializable transaction tries to execute a SQL data manipulation statement that modifies any table already modified by an uncommitted transaction, the statement fails.

READ COMMITTED: If a transaction includes SQL data manipulation statements that require row locks held by another transaction, the statement waits until the row locks are released.

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT DOWNVOTE THIS ANSWER.** I got it from MSDN forums and I am keeping it here for reference.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dcea5f6-32ef-40aa-90d5-0f2fef9e1d38/isolation-level-in-ssis

A few observations...

The IsolationLevel property in SSIS components only applies when distributed transactions are used (package or other container has TransactionOption=Required). So in that regard, Isolation Level is a bit misleading in SSIS. Even if you set it, its not going to help unless a transaction is opened by SSIS. I wrote about that limitation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.isolationlevel.aspx

If you are customizing the isolation level in TSQL (stored procedure or just at the beginning of the a batch) which is called from SSIS, you can override the default SQL Server isolation level Read_committed, however if you just point to a table name in a dataflow source or destination, you can't set the isolation level.

If you choose to manually set the isolation level in other ways in each of your queries, there are a few techniques:

1. If you were to run the SET options in your Commands "set transaction isolation level read uncommitted" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Be careful with Read Uncommitted & Nolock, since it can read dirty data (data changes in flux not fully committed by other connections.)

2. Using Locking Hints such as http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx
   select * from t1 (nolock)
3. Setting the auto-commit isolation level in OLEDB or ODBC if there is a place to override that in the connection string or driver properties of your driver http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175909.aspx I haven't tested that, but it may be possible.

To see the isolation level being used, if your RDBMS that you connect to is SQL Server 2005/2008, while the connection/session is still active you can query DBCC USEROPTIONS or selecting from dm_exec_sessions

select transaction_isolation_level,* from sys.dm_exec_sessions
(0 = Unspecified, 1 = ReadUncomitted, 2 = ReadCommitted, 3 = Repeatable, 4 = Serializable, 5 = Snapshot)

We also found out that Snapshot Isolation Level is incompatible with Distributed Transactions, therefore it is not possible to use Snapshot Isolation Level through the SSIS properties. A workaround for that would be to use the TSQL syntax for Snapshot Isolation within your Data Sources & ExecuteSqlTask commands directly.

Best of luck, Jason
His MSDN Profile -
[Updated 7/23] https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/jasonhowell/activity

Comment: Your last link is not valid.

Comment: Can you tell me how you have found that "Snapshot Isolation Level is incompatible with Distributed Transactions, therefore it is not possible to use Snapshot Isolation Level through the SSIS properties." ?

Comment: I am getting deadlocks in my ssis validation steps when it queries the sql database, and was hoping to set isolation to snapshot to remedy it. I have TransactionOption = Supported (not Required) but I am hitting a deadlock on a query during package validation. SSIS must be generating a transaction if I am hitting a deadlock and I'm not opening a transaction in my own sql right? 

Is it possible Isolation level will help me with TransactionOption = Supported ?

Comment: The link specified near the top, prefixed with "I wrote about that limitation here:" is to the MSDN documentation for the property/setting, not a discussion about its limitations (nor is such a limitation mentioned in the remarks on that page)